# How to exclude a module from the package-lock.json?

Tags: node.js, npm

How to exclude a module from the package-lock.json?

I need to exclude an specific module in order to not be versioned in the package-lock.json. Is this possible?

My problem is that I have a local module (packaged in a different project). For my convenience, I always export this module with the same name: `localmodule-1.1.1.tgz`.

Then I import it in another project like that:

```
...    
"dependencies": {
        "localmodule": "file:../LocalModule/dist/localmodule-1.1.1.tgz"
      },
...
```

Every time I change the contents of the module, the project that is importing it breaks with the error `Unhandled rejection Error: Integrity check failed`. The checksum doesn't match because the content has changed (the checksum is stored in the package-lock.json).

**Is it possible to not include this module inside the package-lock.json?**
I would like to avoid changing the name of the module every time I change any of its contents.

Disclaimer: I am not talking about the versioning of the package-lock.json. The file will be versioned. I am just interested in excluding an specific module from the content of the file itself.

Comment: just don't save the dependency then ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: What do you mean? I need this dependency and it should be included in the package.json to be installed with an ¨npm install¨. If you are referring to install it manually every time it is not really a solution.

Comment: This is a relevant question for use-cases involving relative modules included with the `file://.../my-module` pathing. The `package-lock.json` link SHA won't match that established on `npm install` in another workspace.

Comment: @miqrc Looks like there are a variety of issue active on NPM related to the accuracy of the `package-lock.json` for relative modules. Ref: https://npm.community/t/npm-install-for-package-with-local-dependency-fails/754/26